# Como realizar esta imagen en CSS

Tags: css

Tengo una duda. 
Necesito realizar la siguiente imagen en CSS y no sé como hacerla, ya que comunmente se realizan cortes de torta u otros estilos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento, lo que he realizado es lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.quarter-circle-bottom-right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

Pero no es lo que necesito realmente.
¿De qué manera podria solventar este problema?

Comment: Has hecho algo ya en los CSS ?  mirate la propiedad **border-radius**.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿has intentado algo por ti mismo? Si lo has hecho, sube tu código para ver el avance. Saludos

Comment: Ahh entiendo, la editare @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 6, accepted):

podrias utilizar tambien la pseudo clase `before`.

en este ejemplo podes ver como el dibujo va a tener una posición `relative` mientras que la pseudo-clase `:before` va a estar en posición `absolute`.
damos la medida que queremos a nuesta clase `dibujo`, en este caso utilize un div cuadrado de `200px`y un `overflow: hidden` que va a servir para ocultar la parte extra del `:before`.

sucesivamente le damos la dimencion a nuestra pseudo clase, redondeamos los bordes y lo giramos de `-45°`, le damos el color que queremos y gracias a las propiedades `top` y `left` lo acomodamos como mas nos guste.

```css
.dibujo{
position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dibujo:before{
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 180px;
    height: 210px;
    background-color: green;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 30px;
    left: 40px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="dibujo"></div>
```

**EDIT**

se me olvidava decirte : es importante que la pseudo clase tenga `content: "";` si no no se va a ver !

exitos

Answer (score 6):

Intentándolo hacerlo como tu lo tienes lo conseguí de dos maneras, eso si, siempre utilizando dos elementos, nunca uno.

```css
#cuadradocortado {
            /* background-color: green; */
            position: absolute;
            top: 300px;
            left: 300px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-right: 150px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 150px solid green;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        #mediocirculo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 266px;
            left: 225px;
            width: 211px;
            height: 129px;
            background: green;
            -moz-border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
            border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
            transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
        }

        #circulo {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: blue;
            border-radius: 100px;
        }


        #medioCuadrado {
            background: white;
            height: 222px;
            position: absolute;
            /* border: 1px black solid; */
            width: 34px;
            left: 178px;
            top: 0;
        }

        #medioCuadrado:after {
            background: white;
            content: "";
            height: 73px;
            left: -160px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            width: 181px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="cuadradocortado"></div>
<div id="mediocirculo"></div>

<div id="circulo"></div>
<div id="medioCuadrado"></div>
```

El elemento azul la formo creando un circulo y sobreponiendo divs para tapar partes que no necesito. El segundo elemento, el verde lo hago mediante la unión de medio circulo y medio cuadrado.

En todos los casos espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 5):

Parece que realmente es un círculo traspuesto que se corta en algunas partes. Podrías jugar con el radio de los bordes o con pseudo-elementos como sugieren otros usuarios. Yo te voy a poner otra alternativa: usar un [gradiente radial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) como fondo del elemento.

Con `radial-gradient` puedes crear un círculo sin realmente ningún gradiente si pones los límites entre los colores con el mismo valor (saltará de uno a otro). Entonces es cuestión de jugar un poco con el tamaño y posicionamiento del círculo para que se ajuste a lo que buscas.

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
.quarter-circle-bottom-right {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 69px 80px, #00dd00 70px, #fff 70px);
}
```

Aquí lo puedes ver comparado el que ya tienes:

```css
#show>div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.circle-bg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 69px 80px, #00dd00 70px, #fff 70px);
}

div#div1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eZZY.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="show">
  <div>
    <div>Original:</div>
    <div id='div1' class="circle-bg"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>CSS con radial-gradient:</div>
    <div class="circle-bg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Y ya, si quieres hacerlo más *extensible* para que sea responsivo y se adapte a los cambios de tamaño, en lugar de usar valores con píxeles, usa porcentajes, para el caso de arriba sería así (he tenido que cambiar un poco los valores porque no se veía del todo bien... algo debí calcular mal :/)

```
.quarter-circle-bottom-right {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 57% 66.6%, #00dd00 66%, #fff 66%);
}
```

Así, no importará el tamaño que le pongas al `.quarter-circle-bottom-right`, el círculo se adaptará al tamaño del padre (asumiendo que sea cuadrado) y el fondo se mostrará proporcionalmente igual.

Y otro par de trucos más:

1. Si en lugar de usar #fff, pones como color rgba(0,0,0,0) (`radial-gradient` permite todo tipo de colores, incluso los transparentes), entonces el elemento en lugar de tener fondo blanco tendrá fondo transparente y se verá lo que tenga detrás.
2. Si pones el mismo valor al cambiar de colores, puede verse *feo* porque puede ser demasiado brusco. Si añades un valor un poco más alto al blanco/transparente, entonces el borde se verá más suave.

Aquí puedes verlo incluyendo los dos cambios especificados arriba (el primero es la imagen original que compartiste, el resto son CSS con `radial-gradient`):

```css
.quarter-circle-bottom-right {
display: inline-block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 57% 66.6%, #00dd00 66%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 66.5%);
}

#tama-1 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

#tama-2 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#tama-3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#tama-4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eZZY.png" alt="imagen original" />
<div id="tama-1" class="quarter-circle-bottom-right"></div>
<div id="tama-2" class="quarter-circle-bottom-right"></div>
<div id="tama-3" class="quarter-circle-bottom-right"></div>
<div id="tama-4" class="quarter-circle-bottom-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Usando un elemento y sólo uno de sus pseudoelementos (puede ser `before` o `after`, no hay diferencia) puedes lograrlo sin problemas.

Usando `overflow: hidden` puedes ocultar las partes que sobresalgan asi que sólo resta posicionar el circulo interior (o el pseudoelemento) donde quieras.

Los comentarios en el CSS explican para que sirve cada cosa.

```css
.circulo-cortado {
  /* para contener al pseudoelemento y posicionarlo */
  position: relative;
  /* para ocultar las partes del circulo que sobresalgan al cuadro */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* el tamaño del cuadro contenedor */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.circulo-cortado::after {
  /* para crear nuestro pseudoelemento */
  content: ' ';
  /* para posicionarlo en relacion a su contenedor */
  position: absolute;
  /* las coordenadas para posicionar el circulo interior */
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  /* el color del circulo interior */
  background-color: green;
  /* para que tenga forma de circulo y no de cuadrado */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* diametro del circulo interior */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circulo-cortado"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas cercano que puedes hacer con un solo div y sin "hacks" es usar border-radius de 8 points.
Tienes un editor visual on line para probar en:
https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/full-control.html#47.46.18.23-51.57.100.100-.
Te pongo un ejemplo:

```css
div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:red;
border-radius: 46% 43% 0% 23% / 47% 18% 0% 49%
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```